Sheaf whose stalks vanish at closed points
I am self studying sheaves in algebraic geometry. I am wondering is the following is correct.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on a projective scheme $X$ such the stalk at any closed point $x$, $\mathcal{F}_x$, is zero then does it imply $\mathcal{F}=0$?
I am thinking to use that the set of closed points of a projective scheme is dense, but after that how to proceed? If it is true that there is a neighbourhood of each closed point where the stalk will vanish then we are done but I do not know that it is true or not!
Any kind of hint is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Hint: if a point $\eta$ generizes a point $p$, then $\mathcal{O}{X, \eta}$ is a localization of $\mathcal{O}{X, p}$. (Work affine-locally.)

You should probably also specify exactly what types of sheaves your are working with, e.g. quasicoherent, $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, abelian, etc.

@CJDowd I am working with quasicoherent sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_x$ modules
